# How to upgrade python3-rsa 4.1 version to fix for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04

I have an issue related to CVE-2020-13757 http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2020-13757

Issue related to ***python3-rsa_4.0-3*** in ***Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.***

I did research and found it was fixed in version 4.1, however I couldn't find a package with version 4.1 https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/issues/146, or how to fix the above issue? (I cannot upgrade the Ubuntu version to fix the above issue).
Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can get details from https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2020-13757

It shows the package is fixed with `4.0-3ubuntu0.1~esm1` which is available with normal upgrades for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS if ESM or Ubuntu Pro is enabled.

`python-rsa | 4.0-3            | focal/universe           | source`

The package is a *universe* or *community* sourced package, thus security fixes are only available with Pro enabled (*unless someone from the community uploads the fix via SRU process*).

Thus you can enable Ubuntu *pro* and get the fix with normal upgrades; as only packages in *main* receive security fixes without *pro*.

Comment: The question is, if I install python3-rsa 4.8.1 https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/python3-rsa_4.8-1_all.deb.html of Ubuntu 22.04 into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, will it work? And does it have any impact?